# symbol lookup error libQt5Qml.so.5

Tags: 22.04, qt5

I am new to linux (ubuntu), I don't know what I did, but now I am having some applications not running, example for freecad the error is as follows:

```
freecad: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN15QNetworkRequestC1Ev, version Qt_5
```

I am running Ubuntu 22.04

the output of: `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5` is:

```
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f8036c00000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f8036600000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8036200000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f80374a5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8036fe0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8035e00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f803749e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8036fc4000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007f8036faf000)
    libicui18n.so.70 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.70 (0x00007f8035a00000)
    libicuuc.so.70 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70 (0x00007f8035805000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007f8036b71000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f8036531000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f80360c6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f80375aa000)
    libicudata.so.70 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.70 (0x00007f8033a00000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f80364b9000)
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mistakenly remove the `libqt5network5` package? Check with `apt policy libqt5network5`

Comment: Read the `freecad` documentation - check the requirements.

Comment: libqt5network5:
  Installed: 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2

Comment: It is not only for freecad, other applications also are affected by the same error

Comment: Please add the output of `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5` to your question

Comment: @steeldriver I have edited my question with the output of ```ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5```

Comment: @MehdiCoding thanks - so your system seems to be resolving `libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libQt5Network.so.5` instead of the (presumably correct) `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5`. Have you recently installed another Qt5 application - perhaps by compiling it yourself?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your help, before this problem I was trying to fix my bluetooth, where I have done many manipulations (that I don't understand), please how can I rest resolving ```libQt5Network.so.5``` to ```/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5``` ?

Comment: Did any of your attempted fixes involve setting a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable or creating a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think so, I did many installs, before i found the solution for the bluetooth (copy the driver which was already compiled to a location)

Comment: OK so it looks like the `libc-bin` package adds `/usr/local/lib` to the ld-linux.so search path anyway, so I think you will need to find out WHAT placed an (apparently incompatible) `libQt5Network.so.5` there and decide whether you need to keep it.

Comment: I am trying to locate the package that potentially changed ```libQt5Network.so.5```, is there a way to restore it as default? than if an app is broken I can know which one is causing the issue.

Comment: AFAIK no Ubuntu package installs anything in /usr/local - most likely, this is something you manually downloaded and installed. You may get a clue by looking at what else is in the /usr/local directory tree - especially at what programs you have in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Many thanks @steeldriver, problem solved, I found the application ```AT32_Work_Bench``` which had the ```libQt5Network.so.5```, I removed the application, now everything back to normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @steeldriver for his help, basically I have browsed the applications on `/usr/local` and I found one that had the `libQt5Network.so.5` file.
I have uninstalled the application and now everything is back to normal.